# Change value in div on changing drop down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change value on a div according to selection in drop down box - tried this code but script does not seem to work

HTML dropdown list:

```
<form action="https://ccart.com/cart" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="T-shirt" />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="54" />
    <select name="size" id="Field">
        <option value="1{p-50}">Small</option>
        <option value="2{p-24}">Medium</option>
        <option value="3">Large</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Lets go" class="cart"/>
</form>

    <div id="1" class="box">4</div>
    <div id="2" class="box">30</div>
    <div id="3" class="box">54</div>
```

I tried using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#1').show();
    $('#Field').change(function () {
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Jquery called:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Dropdown working fine but cannot get to show div.

Working fine now but problems changing id from numeric to string as recommended

```
<option value="Small{p-50}">Small</option>
        <option value="Medium{p-24}">Medium</option>
        <option value="Large">Large</option>


<div id="Small" class="box">4</div>
    <div id="Medium" class="box">30</div>
    <div id="Large" class="box">54</div>
```

Code:

```
 $('.box').hide();
           $('#Small').show();
           $('#Field').change(function () {
               $('.box').hide();
               $('#' + parseInt($(this).val())).show();

           });
```

If i leave original id values of 1,2 etc it works perfect

Comment: Because value of dropdown (`1{p-50}`) and ids of divs (`1`) don't match. secondly an id cannot be number alone.

Comment: #3 should appear though

Answer (score 2):

It's failing because of this:

```
    <option value="1{p-50}">Small</option>
    <option value="2{p-24}">Medium</option>
```

Because none of your divs have an ID attribute of `#1{p-50}` it won't be shown.

Unless the `{p-50}` or `{p-24}` are used for anything, just change them to this:

```
    <option value="1">Small</option>
    <option value="2">Medium</option>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ncn4/)

---

Also, as [Sarfraz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596804/change-value-in-div-on-changing-drop-down-using-jquery/22596854#comment34403546_22596804) Mentioned, your IDs should also not be a number alone.

Comment: Missed the non matching divs but i do need {p-50} for price adjustement for cart.

Answer (score 2):

Well values of the dropdown items doesn't match ID's of your divs. If you really want to use them anyway you should use `parseInt`:

```
$('.box').hide();
$('#1').show();
$('#Field').change(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#' + parseInt($(this).val())).show();
});
```

`parseInt` will parse `1{p-50}` to `1` and everything will work.

Note: since numeric ids is not valid in HTML4 you should make sure your define HTML5 doctype which is more tolerant about numbers as identifiers.

Comment: This works perfect after changing ids to match but everytime i try to change ids from numeric to string it breaks.

Comment: Post an example of the new id.

Comment: Html: <option value="1{p-50}">Small</option>

Comment: Last time:Html: <option value="Small{p-50}">Small</option> <div id="Small"class="box">4</div>   <br>$('.box').hide();
               $('#Small').show();
               $('#Field').change(function () {
                   $('.box').hide();
                   $('#' + parseInt($(this).val())).show();
               });

Comment: Basically changed numbers 1, 2, 3 to Small, Medium, Large and updated jquery $('#1') to $('#Small')